# How can we generate unique distinct users for parallel tests with selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

How can we generate unique distinct users for parallel tests with selenium WebDriver and java .
Suppose, in google create an account action I have to pass firstname, lastname, username & Passwd for different browsers.
I have written script & when it was tried to run in parallel on IE, Safari, FF & Chrome, It successfully runs on single browser but for 2nd browser it shows for email Id -"Email already exists".
This is right bcoz we never create more accounts with same ID's.

Now my question is:

How to pass different inputs (strings) in same field textbox for different browsers.
Suppose If we set an array with 4 input strings. should we take random value from this array for different browsers.

an array of multiple inputs
-Email1
-Email2
-Email3
-email4
when we run script in parallely- for first browser it should takes Email1 -When the same script will run for 2nd browser it should takes email2 ..same for 3rd & 4th.

Is it possible in Selenium with java ?

Comment: multiple Gmail creation is illegal.. Try with another site. it is possible with linked list